# Spectral Envelope in Python

Tags: fft, envelope

i have a 192kHz sampled signal that has been measured using an ultrasound MEMS microphone and i want to visualize the spectral envelope. I have found [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29029/envelope-detection-in-frequency-domain-with-matlab) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/734/calculating-a-spectral-envelope) ideas on how to do it (mainly "peak picking in the power spectrum followed by parabolic interpolation"). My data looks like this: [image]

This is not a good envelope. Can someone explain how to set the parameters correct to receive a proper envelope?

Comment: you'd need to show us what your magnitude spectrum looks like; it's hidden by your orange plot, completely. Also, what's not "good" about it? We can't know what you're looking for. What is the quality in a "spectral envelope" that you're looking for?

Comment: Since you only want to visualize, **most of the time** a [`smooth(x)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) on your signal would work well, considering averaging the energy spectrum preserves the total energy. Any other non-linear operation to highlight the peaks would mess with this simple operation.